# For $1 \leq q < p \leq 8$, identify which $p^2 + q^2$ is not prime (Pythagorean Triples)

Tags: number-theory

In my previous question: [Calculating Pythagorean triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360682/calculating-pythagorean-triples), I used

$$x + iy = (p + qi)^2 \hspace{1cm} z = p^2 + q^2$$

to calculate a load of Pythagorean triples (of the form $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$) where $1 \leq q < p \leq 8$ and only one of $p,q$ is odd and the other is even. The follow up question for this says:

> Identify for which of these $p^2 + q^2$ is not prime. You will see two different rows of the table for one of these - and there would be two different rows for another, if the table were continued. Explain this.
>
> *Hint:* If $|p+qi|^2$ is odd $|p+qi|^2 = |(p+qi)^2| = |(p_1 +iq_1)^2(p_2 +q_2i)^2|$ where $p_1 +q_1i$ and $p_2 +q_2i$ are distinct primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and all of $p_1, q_1, p_2$ and $q_2$ are non-zero, then there are two choices for $p + qi$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime which are distinct, even after multiplying by $1$ or $i$. Can you see why?

I don't get if I just need to read off the $p^2 + q^2$ that are not prime to identify them? From the hint, it looks like I need to come up with a general reason as to which ones will be prime and which ones won't be but I don't understand how the hint helps this. Also, I don't really get what tables are being referred to. I've not done anything with tables yet so I it just seems to have come up randomly.

Can anyone help me or give me any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just start it, and (probably) all will get clearer.

I guess, the table wants to mean a $8\times 8$ matrix (as $1\le p,q\le 8$), which is symmetric, so $q<p$ may be assumed (the upper or lower half triangle). Write $p^2+q^2$ in the entries and mark all such that happened to be prime.

There's a theorem that a prime $p$ can be written in the form $p=a^2+b^2$ for some integers $a,b$ iff $p\not\equiv 3\pmod4$. Most probably this time you are only asked to verify this for small examples.